# Port Forwarding rule to make local machine accessible through WAN

Tags: ssh, networking, port-forwarding

I wish to set up a configuration on my home network on one of my machines. Namely, I wish to make it feasible to access it via `ssh` (the machine  runs `dropbear` for `ssh`) but externally. Here's an "image" of the scenario I wish to achieve:

```
+---+  +---+  #1: has the static local IP of 1.2.3.4 and listens to port 22 for incoming ssh connections
|#1 |  |#2 |  #2: has a non-static local IP (DHCP given)
+---+  +---+  #3: 3 wishes to connect to #1
  |      |    GATE: the home modem. Its WAN IP is 5.6.7.8
-----  -----        
  \      \                  +------+
   \______\_________________| GATE |
                            +------+
                               |
  +---+                        |
  |#3 |                     __ | _
  +---+                   _(  )_( )__
    |                    (_ internet_)
  -----                    (_) (__)
    \_________________________/
```

I have followed up and read a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716184/how-to-ssh-into-a-server-running-on-a-home-network-behind-a-router) but I am having some trouble setting up my `port-forwarding` rules on my router's admin web interface and I would like to have some assistance if possible.

In the following image, you can see the options available in order to formulate a port forwarding rule on my modem.
[image: Port Forwarding Menu]

I have specified the imaginary IP address of `#1` (for the sake of simplicity) as `1.2.3.4`. But now, I am not completely sure about the following options. Okay lets say that the `WAN Host Start/End` is the valid range of incoming connections. But then, I am not sure how to proceed with the

1. WAN START/END ports
2. LAN START/END ports

The `ssh` client running on `#1`  listen's to port `22` and thus, I have added that value there. But I am not once again sure on which of START/END it should fall into.

The manual for the displayed fields on the port forwarding menu says the following about those fields:

[image: Port Forwarding Manual]

So, after specifying a WAN port range of `(START,END):=(1,22)` I tried to connect to the machine via:

```
ssh root@5.6.7.8 -p 22
```

But I got a timeout:

> ssh: connect to host 5.6.7.8 port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: I would put all 3 hosts behind the GATE and use a proxy server to accecss the LAN IP address of the GATE - let the GATE route packets between the LAN and the Internet. Also, use ping to test connections - you most likely have a routing problem - putting all the hosts behind the GATE doesn't require changing the routing - and it's a more secure approach if you're novice. Also, If ping doesn't work, then ssh isn't going to work. But if ping does work but ssh doesn't work, then you may have a ssh problem.And you should non-routable IP addresses on you LAN - look at the LAN address for MODEM.

Comment: It's a guess, but I assume the "START/END" settings to be some kind of filter/firewall. As in, "only allow these IPs in from WAN". For the ports its probably the same - but be aware the source port of a connection is different from its destination port.

Comment: @CinaedSimson I can connect to the machine ```#2``` to ```#1``` via ```ssh```. The host ```#3``` cannot be put behind the modem (gate). After enabling the port forwarding rule I tried to connect via ```ssh root@5.6.7.8 -p 22``` but without success.

Comment: @Panki Yes correct. I also tried opening other ports (on the wan side) but I still did not manage to connect

Comment: You should be able to ssh from #1 to #2. In your example - I presume "ssh root@5.6.7.8 -p 22"  would be from either #1 or #2 - which would be an outbound connection -  not an inbound connection. Port forwarding is for inbound connections, i.e., from an external network to an internal network. I doubt if you can do what you're tryihng to do without consulting your Internet provider. Do you have any evidence while logged into the host 5.6.7.8 the host can even ping google.com?

Comment: Seems that the issue was due to the ISP blocking off any of my rules, even though I was allowed to create and 'Enable' them from my web admin interface. After contacting them and asking explicitly to open the ports they told me that they will allow the certain rules. Which means that for every port and forwarding rule I must make, I must explicitly ask them to enable my request. I can now successfully login on ```#1``` from ```#3``` via ssh...